# Why aren't CD image files listed when mounted in current directory?

Tags: filesystems, mount, ls

When mounting a disk image in the current directory using :

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 wall.iso ./
```

Listing files in current directory only returns wall.iso .
To view the actual files on the disk image I must first `cd` out of the directory then back in it.

*Note : if I already knew wall.iso countainted a directory called **subdir**, even tough `ls` didn't list the directory I could already `cd subdir`.*

Why doesn't `ls` return the files when I first call it? Does `ls` read from a cache which is only updated when changing directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're in the directory that you're mounting into. So you're still referencing the original directory's contents through the original directory.

You can see this exact same effect when you are `cd` into a directory that is then deleted.

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/dirtodel

$ rmdir ../dirtodel

$ pwd
/home/saml/dirtodel
```

How can that be? I'm still inside a directory that was just deleted. What's going on?

In the shell that's still `cd` to `/home/saml/dirtodel`, run this command to find out the PID (process id) for it's session of bash:

```
$ echo $$
32619
```

Now if you go into that PID's /proc directory, we can see what's going on a bit:

```
$ ls -l /proc/32619/ | head -10
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 2 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 attr
-r-------- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 auxv
-r--r--r-- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 cgroup
--w------- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 clear_refs
-r--r--r-- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 02:06 cmdline
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 comm
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 coredump_filter
-r--r--r-- 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:40 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 saml saml 0 May 18 07:31 cwd -> /home/saml/dirtodel (deleted)
```

Listing the first few files we see one called `cwd`, which stands for current working directory. Notice it's pointing to our old name and that it's been "deleted".

So that gives us a little insight into what's going on, but where are we?

Interestingly if we `cd /proc/32619/cwd` we can change directories to this magical location. If we run the `df .` command we can see we're still on the `/home` partition:

```
$ pwd
/proc/32619/cwd
[saml@grinchy cwd]$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home
                      245G  125G  108G  54% /home
```

So what's going on?

Even though our directory has been deleted, the inode that makes it up hasn't been. You can see this with the `stat` command. In the shell that's still inside the directory we deleted:

```
$ stat .
  File: `.'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 10486487    Links: 0
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-05-18 07:48:52.674081972 -0400
Modify: 2013-05-18 07:48:44.378900038 -0400
Change: 2013-05-18 07:50:54.189747426 -0400
```

We can see that there's still an inode, 10486487, in use by us, but notice that it has 0 links. That's what happens when something get's deleted. All links to it are removed, and so the OS can then delete this paritcular inode.